# Windows scripting can't import ctypes module under Python 3.11.1

Tags: python

I just ran into a snag after upgrading to Python 3.11.1. Running Python 3.10.1 the `ctypes` module imports with no problems. Same under Windows scripting using the `pywin32` package. With 3.11.1 importing `ctypes` directly still works. However, under Windows scripting using the pywin32 package `import ctypes` fails with the following error output:

```
E:\tmp\test2.pys(12, 0) Python ActiveX Scripting Engine: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<Script Block >", line 12, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "e:\Python\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Anyone else stumbled onto this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I added `e:\Python\DLLs` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and now Windows scripting is able to import the `ctypes` module. I don't claim to know exactly what the cause of the problem was, but it seems that the communication between Python and the `pywin32` package has changed, so that while previously Windows scripting was able to find `_ctypes.pyd` it can no longer do that unless I explicitly tell it where to look. Didn't have to do that before, but everything works again when I do it now.